# If I destroy a civ should I try to convert the cities to my religion?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I have been playing Civ 5 for a while but am new to religion. If I destroy a Civ and captured its holy city, should I try and convert it, even though the other civ's religion is spread further, or let both religions coexist?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, this is kind of a difficult question to answer, since it hinges on a lot of factors. First off, what is your religion like, bonuses-wise, compared to the religion in question that this city is a Holy City of? It may be more beneficial to this city's growth and purpose even if you're not enjoying Founder benefits from its followers.

[Raven Dreamer has already discussed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/101647/7428) how difficult it is to neutralize a Holy City's internal pressure - in short, you need *six* cities in pressure range that follow your religion to keep it on your side. Can you take the Happiness cost that maintaining this would incur? Do you have Missionaries/Great Prophets that can establish this network of pressure? If not, you may not *be able to* flip it to your religion permanently.

If the city isn't a Capital, it may be worthwhile to just raze the city in question and create a new city at the site to claim it for yourself **without** that Holy City taint. Yeah, you'd have to rebuild the city's infrastructure and citizenry, but at least you're not dealing with the religious pressure.